# c# detect powerpoint password protected

Tags: c#, powerpoint

guys. I have a problem that I want to detect a powerpoint(only ppt) document is password-protected or not with C#. I can detect doc/docx/xls/xlsx/pptx now, but just can not detect ppt. I searched on Google for a long time, but I did not find a more satisfactory answer. If you know how to solve this problem, please tell me.

Comment: Want to share your approaches so far? In particular if you already succeeded with other Office-products you should be able to adapt the solution, either allone or at least together with the community. However you have to provide some own approaches and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach in VBA that you can adapt:

```
Sub TestForPassword()

    Dim oPres As Presentation

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oPres = Presentations.Open("c:\temp\open.pptx::xopen::")
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Blimey, you trapped the error!" _
            & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```

The idea is to pass the .Open method a password (in this case xopen).
If it's a password protected file and you pass it the correct password, the file opens.
If it's password protected and you pass an incorrect password, you get an error.
If the file's NOT password protected and you pass an incorrect password, the file still opens and there's no error.

Comment: Works great for me! :)

Comment: @Alex, hi, can you share how this can be verify in C# for provided solution, i wanted to do the same, i can not see password paramter in open method

Comment: @Viral although the original question is about C#, the solution posted here and the solution I tried is for VBA. C# and VSTO are a different story - so, you would need to look elsewhere for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily enough, I find below code is able to open the open-protected and edit-protected ppt:

```
Presentation presentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open($"{presentationFile}::{password1}::", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Viral @Alex It works in C# as well:

```
Presentation presentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open($"{presentationFile}::{password}::", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

The real problem is when file is both open-protected and edit-protected. So far I haven't been able to find a decent c# solution to open such file.